# In Azure powershell set output to table format instead of json

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

In Azure powershell, the json format is annoying at times. Need to scroll backwards and de-crypt .

How do i change the default to be --output table for all az commands?

Comment: Note this question is asking for Azure PowerShell, but you seem to be using Azure CLI. There is a difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure powershell, type the following inorder-to change the default output to table

```
az configure
```

> it will prompt you with following question. Select 3

```
Do you wish to change your settings? (y/N): y

What default output format would you like?
 [1] json - JSON formatted output that most closely matches API responses.
 [2] jsonc - Colored JSON formatted output that most closely matches API responses.
 [3] table - Human-readable output format.
..
Please enter a choice [Default choice(1)]: 3
```

---

This is for users who doesn't like the default json format

Answer (score 1):

Since you've given a solution on how to configure default table output for Azure CLI, this question should also have a solution for Azure PowerShell.

The easiest solution I can think of is just piping the output to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp) e.g. `Get-AzResourceGroup | Format-Table -AutoSize`.

You can have a look for more information at [Format Azure PowerShell cmdlet output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/formatting-output?view=azps-3.6.1).